Colours of visited / not visited questions
Is it only me, or the colouring of question titles is confusing? 
I'm used to think of brighter (more 'crisp') links as not visited, and faded colour would mean visited. On quant.stackexchange it is in reverse (and that way opposite to, for example, stats, server-fault or even this meta). In addition, hover-on colour is hardly noticeable for new links and looks fine for visited links. Saying all this, I understand that some people could be used to the current scheme.
So, is it me or it is actually confusing and hence should be changed?

Quant.SE uses the Beta theme that pervades smaller Stack Exchange sites. We don't get a choice in the matter.
